# Cannot open Visual Studio 2008 files after installing 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I have installed VS 2010 Professional on a machine that already had 2008 Professional. Now I cannot open any 2008 project in VS 2008, even if I explicitly start 2008 and use the Open menu command. However I load the solution or project - Windows Explorer double-click, Send To, or explicit Open - the VS 2010 conversion wizard always starts.

I have tried the following things:

- Restore File Associations in VS 2008
- Make VS Launcher and both devenv.exe's run as Adminstrator by setting their properties.
- Creating a Send To for 2008 files.

Nothing works. The only way I can work with 2008 solutions and projects is to convert them to 2010. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa! The failing solution files were not even 2008, they were VS 2005, which I no longer have on my machine. I thought that they were 2008 files.

It's interesting though that you do not get the option to convert them to 2008 and you are forced to go straight to 2010 format.

Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: I have to wait two days, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Once you covert a solution to VS2010 with the conversion wizard you can no longer open it with VS2008 as the format is no longer supported.

Comment: These are files that haven't been converted - they are still in 2008 format.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have problems opening them in VS2008. But if you try to open them in VS2010 you will be prompted to convert.

Comment: yes that is true. I discovered that those solution files were actually VS 2005 ones, not 2008. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I usually open the project file instead of the solution file with 2008 when I run into this problem, usually works for me. Maybe that helps

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> context menu -> Open with.. -> Visual Studio Version Selector

This will check solution version and launch the appropriate VS

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem - some of the solutions were actually version 2005 and the Version Selector does not give you an option - it forces you to convert to 2010.